# where is `clean.requireForce` set to true?

Tags: git

```
$ git clean
fatal: clean.requireForce defaults to true and neither -i, -n, nor -f given; refusing to clean    
$ git config  -l | grep clean
$
```

"clean.requireForce defaults to true", but where is `clean.requireForce` set to true?  Not in any configure file?

Thanks.

Comment: Just as it says, it *defaults* to `true`: if you haven't set it, it's `true`. If you have set it to `true` it's also true, and if you set it to `false` it's false.

Comment: Are the default values of configuration values not defined in a configuration file?

Comment: They're defined in the source code. For instance, the default for `push.default` is `simple` in Git 2.x but was `matching` in Git 1.x. The default for `diff.renameLimit` has changed three times. Some of these are sometimes announced in the [release notes](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes).

Comment: `true` is not set anywhere, it is implied/defaulted by git unless you specifically change it to `false`. You can set it to `false` by running this command `git config --local clean.requireForce false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the default values of configuration values not defined in a configuration file?

No, they are set by Git itself.

Since the default value is true, you would need to type `git clean -f` to avoid the error message.

Doing a [dry-run](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean#git-clean--n) (`git clean -fn`) is preferable, to test what you are about to clean.